# Shape wont change colour in After Effect

Tags: adobe-after-effects

I'm having this weird problem.

When selecting a colour it doesn't change , goes back to yellow.

All layers are unlocked, is there something I'm missing out ?

Here is an example :

[image]

Answer (score 6):

click the drop down arrow of the "color" property that you're trying to change. there might be an "expression: color" there. if there is click the "=" sign to disable it. That should fix it. (Although double check to make sure that doesn't adversely affect anything else on that layer.

I had the same problem an this fixed it.

Comment: Very accurate....`=` was the issue in my case as well.

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer, couldn't find it for the life of me!